# Proofs With Algebraic Axioms

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-writing

I wanted to check if my proof of this question is sufficient. This is the question:

> Prove that for all $a \in \mathbb{R}$, $a \cdot 0 = 0$.

And the proof:

> Lets assume $a=a$ which implies $a-a=0$.  We must show that $a(0) = 0$.  By (A7), $a(1) = a$ and by (A9) $a(0+1) = a(1) = a$.  By (A3) $a + a(0) = a$ and therefore by subtracting $a$ from each side, $a(0) = 0$.

The axioms are here: [field axioms](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kw0Mx.png)

Comment: This is incomplete.  We don't know what $a(i)$ means nor do we know what $A7$, etc. might refer to.

Comment: Also, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/) to include the problem and your approach.

Comment: How can we check this?  We don't know what A3, A9, etc. are.  If you want us to check the proof, please type it, and explain what axioms you are using.  Please don't post links for matter that can be easily typed.  Links can't be browsed, and they can break.

Comment: I fixed it. I am sorry!

Comment: What is it exactly you are trying to prove. Also, for those who stroll onto this question the axioms are the field axioms.

Comment: Please do not use pictures.

Comment: I am trying to prove a times 0 equals 0 and I am not 100 percent sure if the proof I typed is sufficient as an answer :(

Answer (score 2):

This looks pretty good!  A few comments:

- What is the purpose of your first sentence “Let's assume $a=a$ which implies $a-a=0$.”? There's no need to explicitly assume that $a=a$; it goes without saying.  Furthermore, the statement $a-a=0$ isn't needed or used anywhere else in the proof.
- When you're writing your first proofs with these axioms, it helps to put each equation on its own line, citing the axiom used on that line.  For instance, you write “By (A9), $a(0+1) = a(1) = a$.”  But only the first $=$ is due to (A9); the second is due to (A7).
- Henno's answer reminds me that “subtracting $a$ from both sides” is a bit too quick when you're going step by step with the field axioms.  So do as he suggests, and instead add $(-a)$ to both sides, regroup, and cancel.

Comment: Hi Matthew, thank you for the response. I am not quite sure I follow your second point. Are you referring to stating the entire axiom rather than typing, "(A7)?" Once again, thank you!

Comment: Also, I hope it is not to much trouble but could you please check a couple more of my proofs? I made some adjustments and just wanted to be sure I stated everything efficiently.

Comment: @k.rudin I've expanded my answer, hope it helps.  As for your other proofs, I dip in and out of MSE when I'm procrastinating from other work; if I see another one of your questions at the same time I'll give it a look.  Good luck

Comment: Thank you Matthew! I just had one question actually and that was how to prove that for all ,∈ℝ, ⋅=0 if and only if =0 or =0. Using the same field axioms as before. I am unsure how to approach the problem.

Comment: @k.rudin.  Suppose $ab=0$.  Either $a=0$ or it isn't.  If $a\neq 0$, then use (A8).

Comment: Thank you Matthew. I appreciate all your time and help!

Comment: Suppose ab=0. Either a=0 or it is not. If a̸=0, then by (A8) , there is a unique element a−1 = (1/a)∈ R such that a×a^−1 = a×(1/a) = 1. Thus, b=0. This was my answer

Answer (score 1):

Let $x=a\cdot 0$. Then $x + x = a\cdot 0 + a \cdot 0 = a\cdot(0+0)= a \cdot 0 = x$
where we use A9 first and then A3 to see that $0+0=0$.

Now use the existence of $-x$ (A4): $x+x = x$ so $(x + x) + (-x)=x + (-x)$ (adding $-x$ to both sides of an equality).

But $x + -x = 0$ by A4,  while A2 + A4 + A3 tells us that $(x+x) + -x = x + (x + -x)=x +0=x$. So $x=0$ as we wanted to show.